# Scheduling Algorithms

Tags: algorithm, scheduling

I have a question in my exam that I don't know how to answer it:

Consider that you have a machine for personal use and you are developing various programs. Before going to lunch you want to leave five large programs to compile. In this scenario justifies what / which of the following scheduling algorithms would select: First Come First Served, Shortest Job First, Round Robin or Priority scheduling.

Answer (score 1):

I'd honestly chose `Shortest Job First` for the simple reason that when I come back from lunch I want to have as many programs available to debug and test as possible.

Comment: Probably correct although there is an implicit assumption that compilation has lower priority to whatever other task can be triggered by the user